# Hibernate inheritance hql type

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have dao inheritance in hibernate, here is the code:

```
public class BaseDaoImpl<T> implements BaseDao<T> {
    ...
    protected T findSingle(String hql,Object... params){
      List<T> list = find(hql,params);
      if(list == null || list.isEmpty()){
          return null;
      }
      if(list.size() > 1){
          logger.debug("HQL: {} does not return single element.",hql);
      }
      logger.info("find single: "+list.get(0));
      return list.get(0);
  }
}
```

UserDao:

```
public interface UserDao<T extends User> extends BaseDao<T> {
  ...
  public T getUserByUsername(String username);
}
```

I have a domain class User and two sub-classes of User: Customer and Sales.
I have two dao classes for Customer and Sales accordingly.

UserDao:

```
public class UserDaoImpl<T extends User> extends BaseDaoImpl<T> implements UserDao<T>,BaseDao<T> {
  public T getUserByUsername(String username) {
    return findSingle("from User user where user.username = ?",username);
  }
}
```

CustomerDao:

```
public class CustomerDaoImpl extends UserDaoImpl<Customer> implements CustomerDao {
  private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomerDaoImpl.class);
  public Double getDeposit(Integer id) {
      Customer customer = get(Customer.class,id);
      if(customer != null){
          return customer.getDeposit();
      }
      return 0D;
  }
}
```

SalesDao:

```
public class SalesRepDaoImpl extends UserDaoImpl<SalesRep> implements SalesRepDao{

}
```

My problem is that when I use customerDap to call method getUserByUsername() (which is inherited from BaseDaoImpl) with the sales' username (the user who has the username is an instance of SalesRep, not a Customer), it throws java.lang.ClassCastException, it complains that SalesRep cannot be casted to Customer. As I use customerDao to query the database and it uses the generic type to ensure that the T used in CustomerDao is supposed to be a Customer, how does the findSingle() method in BaseDaoImpl would return an instance of SalesRep in this case, I think it shall return null as no Customer has the username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all -> I assume your using a hibernate inheritance strategy.

The query *"from User"* does hibernate not allow to magically know that your only searching for customers. You have to change the query or your overall mechanic.

**Example solution**

```
public class UserDaoImpl<T extends User> extends BaseDaoImpl<T> implements UserDao<T>,BaseDao<T> {

    protected Class<T> entityClass;

    public UserDaoImpl(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }   
    public T getUserByUsername(String username) {
        return findSingle("from " + getEntityName() + " entity where entity.username = ?",username);
    }

    protected String getEntityName() {
        return entityClass.getSimpleName();
    }
}
```

If UserDaoImpl is not used alone, you can use for example [TypeTools](https://github.com/jhalterman/typetools) to inherit the generic type at runtime.